# How do I save values in Ipy notebook (Jupyter)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a python code to simulate blackjack and am using various functions for dealing, hitting, standing etc. and I'm stuck with the fact that my "hand" won't save between calling different functions.

For example, if I call deal() and it returns my hand and the dealer's hand, then I call hit() it returns a single card, instead of the hand I was dealt and the new card.

I'm wondering how I can get it to save my hand as I thought using append would only add cards to my hand.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import itertools


deck = [val for val in range(2,12) for _ in range(4)]
for i in range(12):
    deck.append(10)
player_hand=[]
dealer_hand=[]

def deal():
    player_hand = []
    dealer_hand = []
    carddeal1 = random.sample(deck,2)
    carddeal2 = random.sample(deck,2)
    for i in range(2):
        deck.remove(carddeal1[i])
        deck.remove(carddeal2[i])
        player_hand.append(carddeal1[i])
    dealer_hand.append(carddeal2[i])
    evaluate(player_hand)
    evaluate(dealer_hand)
    return player_hand,dealer_hand


def hit():
    cardhit = random.sample(deck,1)
    deck.remove(cardhit[0])
    player_hand.append(cardhit[0])
    return player_hand

def dealer_hit():
    cardhit = random.sample(deck,1)
    deck.remove(cardhit[0])
    dealer_hand.append(cardhit[0])

    return dealer_hand

def evaluate(hand):
    if 11 in hand and sum(hand)>21:
        if sum(hand)>31:
            return "bust"
        else:
            return "okay"
    elif sum(hand)==21:
        print "21!!!!"
    else:
        if sum(hand)>21:
            return "bust"
        else: 
            return "okay"

def stand():
    if sum(dealer_hand)>16 and sum(dealer_hand)>sum(player_hand) and 
evaluate(dealer_hand)!="bust":
        print "dealer wins, type deal() to restart"
    elif sum(dealer_hand)>16 and sum(dealer_hand)<sum(player_hand) and 
evaluate(player_hand)!="bust":
        print "You win! type deal() to restart"

    else:
        dealer_hit()
        stand()
```